# C# regex matching exact string in a line but ignore case

Tags: c#, regex

The code for regex that I currently have will look for an exact match with case so what change must I make in order to ignore the case?

```
public static bool ExactMatch(string input, string match)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(match)));
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
public static bool ExactMatch(string input, string match)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(match)), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `(?i)` parameter makes the regex case-insensitive:

```
@"(?i)\b{0}\b"
```

Note that the `\b` word boundaries only work if the search word starts and ends with an alphanumeric character.

Comment: Alphanumeric and underscore characters, actually. A word boundary matches the position in the text where `\w\W` or `\W\w` is true. See [Word Boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w.aspx#WordBoundary)

Comment: @Cyborgx37: You're of course right about the underscore, however, your explanation isn't entirely correct. Word boundaries also match at the start/end of the string (if the string starts/ends with an "alphanumeric" character).

Comment: You are correct. I did not intend to provide a complete defintion (which is given in the linked documentation).

Comment: This (?i) parameter was critical for me because I needed the Regex in an MVC RouteAttribute route variable constraint, where I can't set the RegexOptions.  Best answer for me since it keeps the functionality in the regex string itself.

Answer (score 1):

Server-side, "`(?i)`" can be used, but this doesn't work client-side. 
I guess it should work for you, it will ignore the case.

i.e. "`...(?i)(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|wpf|...`"

Hope it helps.

Comment: "(?i)" works on the client side too.  (It's the same .NET framework in both places.)

Comment: JavaScript does not understand .NET's regular expression syntax for grouping.

When you set EnableClientScript to true on the RegularExpressionValidator ASP.NET re-creates your regular expression in JavaScript to enable client-side validation on you controls. In this case, JavaScript doesn't support the syntax for named groups (?<t>...) and non-capturing groups (?:...).

My answer is 100% correct I don't get why somepeople is like this, giving scores having NO IDEA about what they are talking about.

Comment: While you're correct about JavaScript, the "client side" in this question is C#, not JavaScript.  (Notice the tags.)

Comment: Thats why I'm explainin that if you try to create a startup script and run it in the cliend with javascript it wont work

Comment: What's the point?  He's not asking about web pages or JavaScript.  He's asking about C#.  You brought a completely unrelated concept into the answers for a question.  While it may be accurate, it is unrelated to the question.

Comment: My answer is C#, you should just put it in the regex string.Whats your point?? I told him it work in server side/C#/code behind and give the tip to not use it in client side...

Comment: Without specifying "JavaScript", you said "client side".  There are many kinds of clients.  Your answer (without clarification) would lead someone to believe that C# on the client side behaves differently from C# on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [overload of `Regex.IsMatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktzf2d23.aspx) that allows you to specify options:

```
return Regex.IsMatch(input, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(match)), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

[RegexOption.IgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) should be an option..

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(match)), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```